# Session Handling between a native application and an external application embedded as an iframe

Tags: session, iframe

I have a native web application with complete control over the code and an external application(from an external vendor) embedded within our web application as an iframe. The header and footer of my web application remain, but the body part comes from the external application. 
I have created a session management framework for my application based on the requests that come to my application and it is working fine. 
But if the users start playing around within the iframe part of the application, none of the requests will be routed to my application and hence my web application session will expire while ideally it shouldn't have since for an user everything is one integrated application. How to go about this problem

Comment: Please share the code, describe under which circumstances an error appears and what your expectations are.

Comment: Sorry it's more of an architecture based question, basically my native application has a session timeout of few hours, this session will get renewed if any request comes to my native application, but within the iframe, none of the requests come to my native application but goes to external vendor's application, hence my native application get sessioned out after those few hours, and when the user comes back to my native application, it throws the user out since native application's session has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an approach you can use this approach (i'm basing code on jquery):

- Detect mouse move event

  var lastSync = new Date().getTime();
   var TRIGGER = 60000; //60 seconds of dealy between calls

  $(window).onmousemove(function(event) {

  ```
   if (new Date().getTime() - lastSync > TRIGGER) {

     // Here an ajax call to interact with your backend and refresh session
   }
  ```

  });

So each time a user moves mouse inside the app window event will send and ajax call to your server to refresh the user session.

Hopes this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll try this approach.